# Firebase Admin SDK can't connect to Database from inside jar file

Tags: java, firebase, jar, kotlin, firebase-admin

I'm developing an Android App with Firebase and i've decided to create a simple admin application with the Firebase Admin SDK. Launching with the IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) and connecting to the database via the Admin SDK works fine, but when launching the exported .jar file, the Admin SDK can't connect to the Database. To initialize the connection to Firebase, I use the following (Kotlin) code:

```
//Initialize the Firebase Admin SDK.
val serviceAccount = 
this.javaClass.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("fen/ftcConsole/control/flip-the-classroom-app-firebase-adminsdk.json")
    val options = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://flip-the-classroom-app.firebaseio.com/")
        .setStorageBucket("flip-the-classroom-app.appspot.com")
        .build()
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options)

//Get the connections to the database and the cloud storage.
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
storage = StorageClient.getInstance().bucket()
```

I added a few console outputs and found out that the code just doesn't get past this line: "database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()". It just blocks the thread and nothing happens. Also no exception is thrown.
As I said, this only happens in the exported jar file, when starting with the IDE, everything works fine, which makes testing very hard.

Creating the .jar file with IntelliJ as well as with gradle, packing the dependencies inside the .jar file as well as leaving them outside, loading the .json file with the admin-key from inside the .jar file or from outside, the problem always occurs.

For creating the .jar with gradle, the build.gradle file contains the following jar-block:

```
jar {
   manifest {
       attributes 'Main-Class': 'fen.ftcConsole.gui.GUIStarterKt'
   }
   //adding project files/resources to the jar file
   from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

"gradle jar" gives me a .jar file with all dependencies and resources correctly put inside the file. The application also contains a JavaFX GUI that starts correctly. Only the Firebase connection doesn't work. The same happens when I use the application plugin instead of "gradle jar".

Comment: What exactly are you doing to export this jar?

Comment: I updated the question with the build.gradle content for the jar-file. As mentioned, everything works, except the Admin SDK Database connection.

Comment: Have you considered using the application plugin for Gradle to manage this?  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just tried the application plugin, but unfortunately it gives me the same results. It compiles successfully, starts, but then doesn't get past the connection to the Database.

Comment: This is probably a credential issue. Make sure the credential packaged into the jar is correct, and has access to the database. You can also enable debug logs to see what's going on (use SLF4J or try the [setLogLevel()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) method).

Answer (score 0):

[Deprecated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseCredentials) class:

> FirebaseCredentials
>
> ...
>
> This class was deprecated. Use GoogleCredentials.

from the QuickStart [example](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-java/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/Database.java):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Initialize Firebase
        try {
            // [START initialize]
            FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("service-account.json");
            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                    .setDatabaseUrl(DATABASE_URL)
                    .build();
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
            // [END initialize]
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: invalid service account credentials. See README.");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Shared Database reference
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        // Start listening to the Database
        startListeners();

        // Kick off weekly email task
        startWeeklyTopPostEmailer();
}
```

Using `GoogleCredentials` instead.